# Erro no useEffect ao acessar dados da API

Tags: node.js, react, express.js, react-hooks

Eu tenho o seguinte hook que executa as chamadas a API sem problema, retornando as informações e atualizando os componentes normalmente, mas ele traz alguns erros de conexão no console, creio que esses erros acontecem quando executo a aplicação antes de retornarem as respostas da API, mas como estou usando async await não entendo porque os erros estão ocorrendo, alguém consegue me ajudar com isso:

```
import { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import FinancesDataService from "../services/FinancesService";
import { AppContext } from "../components/context/AppContext";

export const useDetails = () => {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(AppContext);
  const { selectedPeriod, profit, cost } = state;

  useEffect(() => {
    async function countTransactions() {
      const response = await FinancesDataService.countTransactions(
        selectedPeriod
      );
      dispatch({ type: "setCounter", payload: response.data });
    }
    countTransactions();

    async function getProfit() {
      const response = await FinancesDataService.getProfit(selectedPeriod);
      dispatch({ type: "setProfit", payload: response.data });
    }
    getProfit();

    async function getCost() {
      const response = await FinancesDataService.getCost(selectedPeriod);
      dispatch({ type: "setCost", payload: response.data });
    }
    getCost();

    function calcBalance(profit, cost) {
      return profit - cost;
    }
    dispatch({ type: "setBalance", payload: calcBalance(profit, cost) });
  }, [dispatch, selectedPeriod, cost, profit]);

  return {
    counter: state.counter,
    profit: state.profit,
    cost: state.cost,
    balance: state.balance,
  };
};
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
const FinancesModel = require("../model/FinancesModel");

const findPeriods = async (_, res) => {
  try {
    const periods = await FinancesModel.distinct("yearMonth");
    res.send(periods);
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error);
  }
};

const countTransactions = async (req, res) => {
  const period = req.params.period;
  try {
    const counter = await FinancesModel.countDocuments({ yearMonth: period });
    console.info(counter);
    res.send(counter.toString());
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error);
  }
};

const getProfit = async (req, res) => {
  const period = req.params.period;
  try {
    const profit = await FinancesModel.aggregate([
      { $match: { $and: [{ yearMonth: period, type: "+" }] } },
      { $group: { _id: null, value: { $sum: "$value" } } },
    ]);
    res.send(profit[0].value.toString());
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error);
  }
};

const getCost = async (req, res) => {
  const period = req.params.period;
  try {
    const cost = await FinancesModel.aggregate([
      { $match: { $and: [{ yearMonth: period, type: "-" }] } },
      { $group: { _id: null, value: { $sum: "$value" } } },
    ]);
    res.send(cost[0].value.toString());
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error);
  }
};

module.exports = { findPeriods, countTransactions, getProfit, getCost };
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual a response dessas requisições de status 404? É um json válido?

Comment: Estava retornando uma string, eu alterei o controller para retonar um json mas deu o mesmo problema

Comment: Mas existe algum motivo para esta rota ter status 404 (ou algum status de erro)? É normal o navegador printar erros de requisição no console.

Comment: Alterei o post e coloquei o código do controller. Pelo erro dá pra notar que a primeira requisisão chamada findPeriods não dá nenhum erro, mas todas as outras que retornam string dão erro, apesar de estarem funcionando. O que vem do banco nesses três casos é number

Comment: As outras três requisições dependem da primeira, se eu executasse na sequencia acho que não daria erro, mas como tá em um hook creio que ele tenta executar antes de ter o paramentro disponível. Tenho que pensar em uma forma de elas aguardarem o resultado de findPeriods

Comment: O erro ocorre na requisição HTTP. Qual código é responsável por isso (que utiliza `fetch`, `axios` ou `XMLHttpRequest`)? Pelo que parece, `FinancesModel.distinct` usa uma dessas funções sob os panos e pode estar "engolindo o erro", ao invés de propagá-lo. Como a API retorna uma resposta (json) válida com status HTTP errático, isso é logado no console mas não causa nenhuma diferença na aplicação. Mas isso pode ser perigoso, pois caso algum erro real do servidor ocorra, este será engolido ao invés de tratado.

Comment: Ou seja, se possível, mostre o código que chama a API e o código do backend que está retornando 404 com uma resposta válida. O que parece é que o código React em si não tem nada a ver com esse comportamento.

Comment: O código tá todo no github: https://github.com/rafaelcmd/personal-finances

Comment: Acho que pode ser porque não defini os headers na instancia do axios: import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "/api/finances",
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baixei o seu [projeto](https://github.com/rafaelcmd/personal-finances) e tentei debuggar esse problema. Como não tenho acesso ao banco, o app não starta e meu diagnóstico pode não estar 100% correto, mas aqui temos as seguintes possíveis causas:

1. **FinancesRouter.js**

   ```
   app.get("/counter/:period", countTransactions);
   app.get("/profit/:period", getProfit);
   app.get("/cost/:period", getCost);
   ```

   Essas rotas não dão match quando `period` é uma string vazia,
   conforme mostra-se no seu screenshot e conforme eu verifiquei ser a
   primeira requisição que ocorre quando o componente monta. Evite
   chamar a API com este parâmetro em branco. Para verificar se é isso mesmo, teste com uma data não-vazia e verifique se o status code é 200.
2. A porta da API nos seus prints é a 3000, comumente a porta utilizada
   pelo Create React App. No entanto, se este fosse seu problema, haveria outro status code (437 para mim). Verifique se isto está correto.

Comment: Valeu pela dica Rodrigo, coloquei um parâmetro fixo em cada rota e os erros sumiram. Vou colocar umas condições pra só executar quando tiver o dado vindo da primeira requisição.

Comment: Que bom que funcionou. Como o problema na verdade era no node/express, vou colocar essas tags na pergunta.

Comment: Na verdade eu não mudei nada no node, só criei um if no hook pra só executar as requisições quando o parâmetro existir. Mas é melhor alterar as tags mesmo.